# How To add a shortcut key to the terminal in LXDE?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

Hi I am new to GNU/Linux. I searched the web and saw that the most common shortcut to the terminal is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, however this doesn't work for me.

This prompts two questions. First, do the shortcut keys depend on the desktop environment or on the Linux distribution?

Second, how can I add a custom shortcut to an specific program in LXDE (in this case the LX terminal)?

PS: In LXDE I can't see the option "shortcut key" or something similar right-clicking on a `.desktop` file and going to properties. Also going to shortcuts and gestures in system settings, I see that I can add a custom shortcut, but I don't know how to point it to the LX terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key bindings come mostly from desktop environment, although linux distributions may set some "default" in config files.

You can point to "LX terminal" by the name of its program which is called `lxterminal`. For example inside LX terminal you can write 'lxterminal' to run another instance/window of terminal.

Answer (score 17):

If you use LXDE, open box, and you want to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open the `LXTerminal`, you need to add

```
<!-- Launch LXTerminal with Ctrl+Alt+t-->
    <keybind key="C-A-t">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>lxterminal</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
```

to `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`.

Key bindings are found in the `<keyboard>` section of your rc.xml configuration file. Any bindings outside of that section are not valid and will be ignored.

Comment: Lubuntu users may be interested in [Lubuntu/Keyboard - Community Help Wiki - Create New Keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Create_New_Keyboard_shortcuts)

Comment: More details in Openbox official documentation [Help:Bindings - Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings)

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem while running LXDE on rpi.
For me it started working when I added following lines into
"**~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml**" this file.

```
<keybind key="C-A-t">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxterminal</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Answer (score -1):

Click on system tools > terminal , right click > add to desktop

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  I think the OP was looking for a keyboard shortcut rather than a permanent icon.